# How download "octet-stream" Data from a web service and convert in image in WP8?

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, content-type

Im new with WP8.
Im asking which class i should use to get data from a webservice.
I need to launch many Asynchronous requests. 1request=1 image and i need a lot of image in my UI.
in a first time i tried with the webclient class but i can't manage the content type "application/octet-stream" with it so at this time im trying to use the HttpClient class but I need your help. I also need to use Authentication with credantials to connect to the webservice.
In a second time i need to convert the data obtained in Bitmapimage.But i think it's an easier part.I would probably use the Stream class for that.*

thanks for your help 
Sry for my english BTW :p

Im not sure it would help but i join a sample of the code,i used a dictionnary of HttpClient because i encountered an error while trying to launch several async requests on the same instance of a Webclient... the 2 lists remain empty...

```
Dictionary<string, HttpClient> HttpClientDic = new Dictionary<string, HttpClient>();
List<byte[]> imageDataBlocksPresta = new List<byte[]>();
List<byte[]> imageDataBlocksCollab = new List<byte[]>();

    public async Task< List<byte[]>> DownloadAsyncRecherchePhoto(string uri,string critere = "")
    {
        string password = Authentification.MainPage.Password;
        string user = Authentification.MainPage.User;
        string domain = Authentification.MainPage.Domain;

        i++;

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain) };
        HttpClientDic.Add("Client" + i.ToString(), new HttpClient(handler));

        if (critere == "presta")
        {
            imageDataBlocksPresta.Add(await HttpClientDic["Client" + i.ToString()].GetByteArrayAsync(uri));
            return imageDataBlocksPresta;
        }
        else if (critere == "collab")
        {
            imageDataBlocksCollab.Add(await HttpClientDic["Client" + i.ToString()].GetByteArrayAsync(uri));
            return imageDataBlocksCollab;
        }

            //gérer l'erreur
        else return null;
```

Comment: could you post your code attempt of what you're trying to do ?

Comment: When I wrote my own WP8 app I got an error saying there can be only one web request at a time. I found this very surprising.